# Create a list with a certain name (using assign) and put values into it in R

Tags: r

I am new to R and want to do the following: create a list outside of my for loop, and then fill it up inside - the tricky part is I want the list to be created with a certain name, and for that I'm using assign. I'm having troubles calling that again inside my loop.

Hopefully my example will make things clearer (the actual code does more inside the loop, but this the relevant part):

```
age_list = list(list(17:19, 20:23), 
            seq(from= 17,to=50, by=1))
ind_out <- "emp"
l_name <- paste0("out_stats_", ind_out)
# i create the new variable here,  you can see it in the env.

assign(l_name,vector(mode = "list", length = length(age_list))) 

for (g in 1:length(age_brackets_list)){
  
  out1 = data.frame(name = g) 
  
  # and now i wanna put this element into my new variable that i've created, but i can't call it, or use assign
  
  # i've tried 
  #assign(l_name, out1)
  #assign(l_name[[1]], out1)
  #do.call("<-", list(l_name[[g]], out1))
}
```

With `assign`, the code replaces the list I've created with the new dataframe - I understand this is what assign does, so that doesn't work. With `do.call` I run into an error at `g=2` because it's not recognized as a list (the variable represented by l_name only has one dimension (?)).

Any help appreciated!

Comment: I am confused. What is the expected output? Your code works with `assign(l_name, out)`.

Comment: @slava-kohut I want the final output (the variable with the name l_name) to be a list of dataframes, and when I run it the code it's just 1 dataframe (the final one).  It's replaced in every iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `assign` once on a list of data frames produced by `lapply` (substitute for a loop):

```
age_list = list(list(17:19, 20:23), 
                seq(from= 17,to=50, by=1))
ind_out <- "emp"
l_name <- paste0("out_stats_", ind_out)
assign(l_name, lapply(1:length(age_list), function(x){
#
# more code
#
data.frame(name=g)}))
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for the simple example but I think I've provided too simple an example. There are a lot more things going on inside the loop (the dataframe in question is actually an output from a function that i call, which requires its arguments to be created in the loop) - so I can't really get rid of it. Any way to do it inside?

Comment: @ladyp then add all actions you want to perform to the function inside `lapply`

Comment: Ok this worked out great! I still have one question if you can help for it to work for mem but more related to `lapply` I guess. In my loop I was using the index g to select elements of age_list, and use the values, and I can't seem to do that using `lapply`. To be explicit, I was doing `for (g in 1:length(age_list){age_brackets = age_list[[g]]} `and so on.

Comment: In this case, you can use `x` (function argument) as index because `lapply` iterates over `1:length(age_list)`

Comment: Perfect, thanks so much! Everything works. Is it better practice to use `lapply` than for loops in R?

Comment: It depends on your goal. Generally, yes.